# Tomcat : Issue with catalina.out file too big on Windows server

Tags: linux, windows, tomcat7, catalina.out

When I was running my webapp (J2EE / Tomcat)  on a linux server, I had no problem with `catalina.out` file thanks to `logrotate` process on linux.

But on Windows environments this doesn't exist, and *catalina* file is getting very big.

Is there a way to handle this issue on Windows?

Thanks

Comment: You may wanna check out this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8342336/how-to-set-maximim-number-of-rolls-and-maximum-log-size-for-tomcat